# Error while starting my project ( after running ng serve )

Tags: angular, node-modules

I downloaded the zip file of the project from the online MOOC I am learning. It was working fine until now but now I am facing the error as described below :-

I tried running `ng serve` again and also running `npm install` again but every time I encounter the following error:

> ERROR in node_modules/rxjs-compat/operator/shareReplay.d.ts(2,10):
>   error TS2305: Module '"/Users/ratnabhkumarrai/Downloads/prj-http-final
>   3/node_modules/rxjs/internal-compatibility/index"' has no exported
>   member 'ShareReplayConfig'.

```
import { Observable, SchedulerLike } from 'rxjs';
import { ShareReplayConfig } from 'rxjs/internal-compatibility';
/**
* @method shareReplay
* @owner Observable
*/
export declare function shareReplay<T>(this: Observable<T>, config: 
ShareReplayConfig): Observable<T>;
export declare function shareReplay<T>(this: Observable<T>, 
bufferSize?: number, windowTime?: number, scheduler?: SchedulerLike): 
Observable<T>;
```

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: @JohanRin rxjs 6.4.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to downgrade rxjs-compat and was able to get past it.

`"rxjs-compat": "6.3.3"`

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I resolved just installing the same version of rxjs and rxjs-impat. The problem was that I had rxjs version 6.3.3 and rxjs-impat 6.4.0. I upgraded rxjs to 6.4.0 version. Having rxjs 6.4.0 and rxjs impat 6.4.0 version solved the problem

Comment: @NazrulMuhaimin 

Answer (score 3):

there are some packages to update:

```
  Name                               Version                  Command to update
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/cli                       7.2.4 -> 7.3.1           ng update @angular/cli
  @angular/core                      7.2.3 -> 7.2.4           ng update @angular/core
  rxjs                               6.3.3 -> 6.4.0           ng update rxjs
```

There might be additional packages that are outdated.Run

```
ng update --all
```

to try to update all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rxjs 6.4.0, you don't need to use `rxjs-compat`, which provides a compatibility layer between rxjs v6 and v5.

So I think you can directly use `import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';`

More information on the operators here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/